# Split a file into two files based on a word

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

> Write Shell script to split the below file into two files
> `male_nominee.txt` and `female_nominee.txt` based on gender. If file
> `male_nominee.txt` or `female_nominee.txt` already exists, then append
> the content.
>
> Display the contents of `female_nominee.txt` and `male_nominee.txt`
>
> `names.txt`
>
> ```
> 23|Arjun|Male
>
> 24|Akshara|Female
>
> 17|Aman|Male
>
> 19|Simran|Female
> ```

My code:

```
while IFS= read -r line;
do
    if i=$(grep "Male" names.txt)
    then
        echo "$line" >> male_nominee.txt
    fi
    if j=$(grep "Female" names.txt)
    then
        echo "$line" >> female_nominee.txt
    fi
done < "names.txt"
ls
cat male_nominee.txt
cat female_nominee.txt
```

In my output, I have the contents of `names.txt` in both my files. Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Classes usually have some pretty terrible assignments but this is one of the worst ones I've seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few more variations:

#### awk — single pass

```
awk -F'|' '
   $3 == "Male"   { print >> "male_nominee.txt"   }
   $3 == "Female" { print >> "female_nominee.txt" }
          ' names.txt
```

Similar to [jesse_b’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/605480/80216#605482), but it reads the file only once
and does the I/O redirection within the awk script. 
Note that these awk answers allow the data format to be modified; e.g.,

```
age|name|sex|height|weight|…
```

but they will ignore a line where there is a space
between the second `|` and the sex.

#### bash

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
        if [[ $line =~ Male$ ]]
        then
                printf '%s\n' "$line" >> male_nominee.txt
        fi
        if [[ $line =~ Female$ ]]
        then
                printf '%s\n' "$line" >> female_nominee.txt
        fi
done < names.txt
```

I guess this is what you were trying to do — read each line into the shell
and test whether the sex is male or female.

- jesse is right, in general:
  You should generally avoid reading files with a `while read` loop. 
  See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/80216) 
  But one of the drawbacks of using a shell loop to process text
  is that people often invoke an external utility
  on each iteration of the loop,
  and this example doesn’t do that.
- Also, if you are given an artificial assignment
  to do something *entirely in the shell,*
  then you should follow the rules of the assignment.
- This is more tolerant of spaces in the file,
  but does not allow additional data after the sex.
- In bash, `=~` compares a string to a regular expression. 
  In a regular expression, `$` means the end, so `$line =~ Male$`
  checks whether `$line` *ends with* `Male`. 
  If we just said `$line =~ Male` (without the `$`),
  then a woman whose name was Maleficent would be counted as a man.
- If you’re worried about backslashes (`\`) in the data,
  use `read -r` instead of just `read`.
- It probably doesn’t matter in this case
  (if every line begins with a number),
  but, in general, `printf` is safer than `echo`.

#### POSIX shell

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line
do
        case "$line" in
            (*Male)
                printf '%s\n' "$line" >> male_nominee.txt
                ;;
            (*Female)
                printf '%s\n' "$line" >> female_nominee.txt
                ;;
        esac
done < names.txt
```

- This will be more portable than the bash version.
- `case` is the traditional way
  of testing a string against pattern(s) in the shell. 
  It uses filename matching (i.e., glob) patterns
  instead of regular expressions.
- A glob pattern must match, so we need to put a `*` before the sex values. 
  If we checked for `Male` (without the `*`),
  it would match only lines that were *only* the word `Male`
  (i.e., without an age and a name). 
  On the other hand,
  this means that we don’t need to put any marker on the end.

Answer (score 1):

The "Display the contents of female_nominee.txt and male_nominee.txt" requirement is sort of unclear and IMO has no place in the script but I've included it anyway.   You should generally avoid reading files with a while read loop, and since this is a delimited file it is easily managed with awk:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh 

infile=./names.txt

awk -F\| '$3 == "Male"' "$infile" >> male_nominee.txt
awk -F\| '$3 == "Female"' "$infile" >> female_nominee.txt

cat male_nominee.txt female_nominee.txt
```

---

Additionally, some issues with your script:

Your `if` statements are grepping from `names.txt` instead of `line` since that file contains both `Male` and `Female` both conditions will pass every time.

There is no need to assign to a variable in each line, that variable is never being used.  You could just do `if echo "$line" | grep -q 'Male'; then`

You don't need two if statements since it will be if/else

```
if echo "$line" | grep -q 'Male'; then
  echo "$line" >>male_nominee.txt
else
  echo "$line" >>female_nominee.txt
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the statement

> ```
> if i=$(grep "Male" names.txt)
> ```

will:

1. Search "Male" in the whole `names.txt`
2. Return the output ("all the lines containing Male") assigning that to variable `i`
3. If *the assignment* was successful (should always be), execute the content of the if

As you are reading line by line, you probably want to check only that line.

You can do that with `if echo "$line" | grep -q "Male"` (or, if you want to avoid -q, which is not defined by POSIX, redirect the output to `/dev/null`)

Note that this will search for "Male" in the whole line, so it could fail if e.g. you had someone called "AMalek" in the file.

As you are reading line by line, rather than your read, you could use `IFS="|"  read -r age name gender` and then just an `if [ $var = "value" ];`

Another option, using grep, would be to require a leading "|" (note it is a special character) and that it ends the line.

Note that in such case you could replace the whole loop with a couple of greps.

(the error with females is exactly the same as with males)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

 grep  "male$" names.txt | cat >> female_nominee.txt

 cat female_nominee.txt

 grep "Male" names.txt | cat >> male_nominee.txt

 cat male_nominee.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Would you mind explaining what this script does, and how? Why do you need to pipe the output of `grep` to `cat`, and redirect _that_ to the files, instead of directly redirecting the output of `grep`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution using grep to filter and ">>" to append.

```
grep "Female$" names.txt >> female_nominee.txt
grep "Male$" names.txt >> male_nominee.txt

cat female_nominee.txt
cat male_nominee.txt
```